# Sql server 2008: linked server not working

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I have a problem on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a db_datareader user U, on a database X in server Y .

If I try to connect on these server Y from server Z using a LINKED SERVER I see only few tables, but if connect directly on Server Y with this user I see all tables.

Why?